# Error: invariant expected app router to be mounted why this happened when using react testing library

Tags: next.js, react-testing-library, ts-jest

when i use react-testing-library, it says that error: invariant expected app router to be mounted , it has no such problem when running in the development environment.

the testing logics is here

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react"
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event"
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar";

describe("<NavBar>", () => {
    it ("the login pop out displayed after click the login/sign up button", async () => {
        render(<NavBar />);

        const loginButton = screen.getByRole("link", {
            name: "LOGIN/SIGN UP"
        });
        const loginCard = screen.getByTestId("loginCard");

        await userEvent.click(loginButton);
        expect(loginButton).toBeCalled();
        expect(loginCard).toBeVisible();
    })
});
```

the components is here:
Navbar:

```
"use client"

import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

interface NavBarProps {
  setVisibleLogin?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const NavBar = ({ setVisibleLogin }: NavBarProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleLoginBtn = () => {
    setVisibleLogin && setVisibleLogin(true);
  };

  const handleHome = () => {
    router.push("/");
  };

  return (
    <div className="bg-slate-50 flex justify-center">
      <div className="fix w-912px top-0 navbar w-require">
        <div className="navbar-start">
          <a
            className="btn btn-ghost normal-case text-xl text-sky-500"
            onClick={handleHome}
          >
            Alimama MealGPT
          </a>
        </div>
        <div className="navbar-center hidden lg:flex"></div>
        {
          // for distinguish between the page for login and others
          setVisibleLogin && (
          <div className="navbar-end">
            <a className="btn" onClick={handleLoginBtn}>
              Login/Sign Up
            </a>
          </div>
          )
        }
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default NavBar;
```

LoginCard:

```
"use client"

import React, { Dispatch, SetStateAction } from "react";
import InputBox from "./InputBox";
import Image from "next/image";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

import GoogleLoginCard from "@/assets/btn_google_signin_dark_normal_web@2x.png"

interface LoginCardProps {
  visibleLogin: boolean;
  setVisibleLogin: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

const LoginCard = ({visibleLogin, setVisibleLogin}: LoginCardProps) => {
  const router = useRouter();

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setVisibleLogin(false);
  }

  const handleSignUp = () => {
    router.push("/SignUp");
  }

  return (
    <div 
    className="fixed left-1/2 top-1/2 -translate-x-2/4 -translate-y-2/4 z-50" 
    style={{ visibility: visibleLogin ? "visible" : "hidden" }}>
      <div className="card w-96 bg-neutral text-neutral-content bg-slate-200">
        <div className="flex flex-row-reverse">
          <div className="flex flex-row-reverse" style={
            {
              position: "relative",
              top: "0.5rem",
              right: "0.5rem"
            }
          }>
            <button className="btn btn-outline w-2 h-2" onClick={handleCancel}>X</button>
          </div>
          <a className="relative right-10 top-3 btn btn-ghost normal-case text-xl text-sky-500">Alimama MealGPT</a>
        </div>
        <div className="card-body items-center text-center">
          <h2 className="card-title">Login</h2>
          <InputBox
            title="Email/ User ID"
            textHolder="Please Enter Your Email or ID Here"
            otherLeftOption={false}
            otherRightOption={false}
          />
          <InputBox
            title="Password"
            textHolder="Please Enter Your Password Here"
            otherLeftOption={true}
            otherRightOption={true}
            optionLeftText="Forget Password?"
            optionRightText="Any Other Helps?"
          />
          <div className="card-actions justify-end">
            <button className="btn btn-primary w-27">Log In</button>
            <button className="btn btn-primary w-25" onClick={handleSignUp}>Sign Up</button>
            <button className="btn btn-outline" onClick={handleCancel}>Cancel</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <Image src={GoogleLoginCard}
              height={200}
              width={200}
              alt="google login button"
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default LoginCard;
```

I saw some other similar question have such solution like add the html head and body tag on layout.tsx, i put head and body tag in layout.tsx already.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

I expect the solusion for fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried mocking useRouter? Check this out: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7479

Answer (score 20):

For me it worked to mock useRouter in the Jest test like this:

```
imports ...

// Mock useRouter:
jest.mock("next/navigation", () => ({
  useRouter() {
    return {
      prefetch: () => null
    };
  }
}));

describe("Test something", () => { ...
```

The idea was taken from [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/7479#issuecomment-545212303) (I just changed "next/router" to "next/navigation").

Answer (score 6):

**In a real Next.js application** your components tree is wrapped in a whole bunch of different providers under the hood.

```
 // from the Next.js source code...
 <AppRouterContext.Provider value={adaptedForAppRouter}>
    <SearchParamsContext.Provider value={adaptForSearchParams(router)}>
      <PathnameContextProviderAdapter
        router={router}
        isAutoExport={self.__NEXT_DATA__.autoExport ?? false}
      >
        <PathParamsContext.Provider value={adaptForPathParams(router)}>
          <RouterContext.Provider value={makePublicRouterInstance(router)}>
            <HeadManagerContext.Provider value={headManager}>
              <ImageConfigContext.Provider
                value={
                  process.env
                    .__NEXT_IMAGE_OPTS as any as ImageConfigComplete
                }
              >
                {children}
              </ImageConfigContext.Provider>
            </HeadManagerContext.Provider>
          </RouterContext.Provider>
        </PathParamsContext.Provider>
      </PathnameContextProviderAdapter>
    </SearchParamsContext.Provider>
  </AppRouterContext.Provider>
```

When you call `useRouter()` in your component it tries to get router instance from the `AppRouterContext` and throws error when it is not able to read it.

```
// from the Next.js source code...
export function useRouter(): import('../../shared/lib/app-router-context.shared-runtime').AppRouterInstance {
  clientHookInServerComponentError('useRouter')
  const router = useContext(AppRouterContext)
  if (router === null) {
    throw new Error('invariant expected app router to be mounted')
  }

  return router
}
```

**In your unit tests** components are rendered in isolation. That means when you are calling `render(<MyComponent />)` in your test it knows nothing about the providers in a tree above that are present in a real Next.js or a plain React application.

So when a call to `useRouter` is made in your component under the test and a real `useRouter` from `next/navigation` hook is used and corresponding context provider is not available / not passed the correct value it will attempt to read the context, fail to do so and throw the error.

Generally, as stated in React Testing Library documentation, it's a good approach to use [custom `render`](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/setup#custom-render) to automatically wrap your component under test in all the providers that are present in your app.

Another option is just to mock (or partially mock) the modules that read from context like this...

```
// example is for Vitest, but it's very similar for Jest
vi.mock('next/navigation', async () => {
  const actual = await vi.importActual('next/navigation');
  return {
    ...actual,
    useRouter: vi.fn(() => ({
      push: vi.fn(),
      replace: vi.fn(),
    })),
    useSearchParams: vi.fn(() => ({
      // get: vi.fn(),
    })),
    usePathname: vi.fn(),
  };
});
```

In the above example the real `useRouter` hook from `next/navigation` module is replaced with the mock function that doesn't read from the context (so, the **invariant expected app router to be mounted** error will not to be thrown anymore) and just returns a fake `router` object with a couple of methods (`push`, `replace`) which in turn are also set to be mock functions.

If it suites your needs, you can also mock other exports / methods (like `useSearchParams` and `usePathname`) and change their implementation.

Such setup can be done either only once in a test setup file or on a per test basis.